# Netlyfy: CKEditor5 - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')

Tags: ckeditor, netlify

I've been deploying normally but last deploy is showing me this:

```
1:58:34 PM: build-image version: 4c0c1cadee6a31c9bb8d824514030009c4c05c6a (focal)
1:58:34 PM: build-image tag: v4.15.0
1:58:34 PM: buildbot version: 44377b3b6a4027dd8a09c3df7d29646ce9192423
1:58:34 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
1:58:34 PM: Starting to download cache of 419.1MB
1:58:38 PM: Finished downloading cache in 4.318992901s
1:58:38 PM: Starting to extract cache
1:58:48 PM: Finished extracting cache in 9.085548565s
1:58:48 PM: Finished fetching cache in 13.475179533s
1:58:48 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
1:58:48 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
1:58:51 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
1:58:52 PM: Section completed: initializing
1:58:52 PM: Starting build script
1:58:52 PM: Installing dependencies
1:58:52 PM: Python version set to 2.7
1:58:52 PM: Started restoring cached node version
1:58:53 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
1:58:53 PM: v16.18.1 is already installed.
1:58:53 PM: Now using node v16.18.1 (npm v8.19.2)
1:58:54 PM: Enabling node corepack
1:58:54 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
1:58:54 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
1:58:54 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
1:58:54 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
1:58:55 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
1:58:55 PM: Started restoring cached yarn cache
1:59:00 PM: Finished restoring cached yarn cache
1:59:00 PM: No yarn workspaces detected
1:59:00 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
1:59:00 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
1:59:01 PM: Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.22.19
1:59:01 PM: yarn install v1.22.19
1:59:01 PM: warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
1:59:01 PM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
1:59:12 PM: [2/4] Fetching packages...
1:59:14 PM: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
1:59:14 PM: warning "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils > ts-loader@9.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
1:59:14 PM: warning "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils > ts-loader@9.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^5.0.0".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > bootstrap@4.6.1" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.16.1".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > v-calendar@2.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "@popperjs/core@^2.4.0".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > vue-cropperjs@5.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "vue@>=3.0.0".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > vue-instantsearch@4.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "algoliasearch@>= 3.32.0 < 5".
1:59:14 PM: warning "vue-instantsearch > instantsearch.js@4.40.4" has unmet peer dependency "algoliasearch@>= 3.1 < 5".
1:59:14 PM: warning "vue-instantsearch > instantsearch.js > algoliasearch-helper@3.8.2" has unmet peer dependency "algoliasearch@>= 3.1 < 5".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.17" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@>= 1.6.0 < 7.0.0".
1:59:14 PM: warning "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint > eslint-loader@2.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@>=1.6.0 <7.0.0".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > vue-loader@15.9.8" has unmet peer dependency "css-loader@*".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > @vue/eslint-config-prettier@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-prettier@^3.1.0".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > @vue/eslint-config-prettier@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "prettier@>= 1.13.0".
1:59:14 PM: warning " > eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0".
1:59:18 PM: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
1:59:18 PM: success Saved lockfile.
1:59:18 PM: Done in 17.36s.
1:59:18 PM: NPM modules installed using Yarn
1:59:18 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
1:59:18 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
1:59:18 PM: Installing Go version 1.17 (requested 1.17)
1:59:23 PM: unset GOOS;
1:59:23 PM: unset GOARCH;
1:59:23 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.17.linux.amd64';
1:59:23 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.17.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
1:59:23 PM: go version >&2;
1:59:23 PM: export GIMME_ENV="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.17.linux.amd64.env"
1:59:23 PM: go version go1.17 linux/amd64
1:59:23 PM: Detected 1 framework(s)
1:59:23 PM: "vue" at version "4.5.17"
1:59:23 PM: Installing missing commands
1:59:23 PM: Verify run directory

1:59:25 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
1:59:25 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
1:59:25 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
1:59:25 PM: ​
1:59:25 PM: $ npm run build
1:59:25 PM: > oceanly@1.0.0 build
1:59:25 PM: > vue-cli-service build
1:59:26 PM: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
1:59:26 PM:   npx browserslist@latest --update-db
1:59:26 PM:   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
1:59:26 PM: -  Building for production...
1:59:27 PM:  ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')
1:59:27 PM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')
1:59:27 PM:     at getCompilationHooks (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin/lib/servetranslations.js:206:29)
1:59:27 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin/lib/servetranslations.js:95:3
1:59:27 PM:     at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:21:1)
1:59:27 PM:     at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
1:59:27 PM:     at Compiler.newCompilation (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:631:26)
1:59:27 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:667:29
1:59:27 PM:     at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
1:59:27 PM:     at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
1:59:27 PM:     at Compiler.compile (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:28)
1:59:27 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:321:11
1:59:27 PM:     at Compiler.readRecords (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:529:11)
1:59:27 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:318:10
1:59:27 PM:     at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
1:59:27 PM:     at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
1:59:27 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:315:19
1:59:27 PM:     at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
1:59:27 PM: ​
1:59:27 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
1:59:27 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
1:59:27 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

I can not understand which 'version' is referenced here.

I have been searching about this error. I compared with my previous good deploy 3 days ago..

the difference is related with these lines:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')
    1:59:27 PM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')
    1:59:27 PM:     at getCompilationHooks (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin/lib/servetranslations.js:206:29)
```

[image]

I was thinking was related with webpack, so I executed this:

```
npm list webpack
```

then I save it in package.json with:

```
npm install --save-dev "webpack@4.46.0"
```

All is working in my dev environment, but when I deploy with Netlify it is generating the error.

Answer (score 1):

The previous versions of `CKEditor` 31.1.x had issues with `webpack v4.46.0`. I tried to update to webpack v5 but the error persisted. So I searched in the official documentation of the pluggin, and I found last releases solving problems with CKEditor and `webpack`. I reported the issue to the development team in GitHub and they solved it.

The solution was wait until the new release **(v31.1.11)** and install it.

Run these lines to get last version of the plugins:

```
npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils
npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin
```

In case you are using more pluggins of `CKEditor` run the others pluggins detailed in the release

> @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-docs: v31.1.11 => v31.1.12

> @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-env: v31.1.11 => v31.1.12

> @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-tests: v31.1.11 => v31.1.12

> @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils: v31.1.11 => v31.1.12

> @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin: v31.1.11 => v31.1.12

> @ckeditor/jsdoc-plugins: v31.1.11 => v31.1.12

Oficial documentation: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev

Issue reported: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/12887

Change log: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Especial thanks to [pomek](https://github.com/pomek)

Comment: I encountered this issue installing the latest version of Mautic 5.0 and this solution fixed my dependency issue.  Thank you!